# mvc3 Routes setup as id, id2 id3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following area routes setup.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default3",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}/{id3}",
    new { action = "Index" }
);
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default2",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
    new { action = "Index"}
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When a controller action is hit I do something like the following where I place the params into readable variable names.

```
public ActionResult Search(Guid? id, int? id2, bool? id3)
{
    Guid? source = id;
    int daysOld = id2;
    bool includeNonEnglish = id3;

    //.... Action!
}
```

Should I continue that way? Should I create a plethora of routes?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create more routes. That way, you have things like:

```
Html.ActionLink(title, "Action", "Controller", new { source = <value>, daysOld = <value>, includeNonEnglish = <value> });
```

Instead of:

```
Html.ActionLink(title, "Action", "Controller", new { id = <value>, id2 = <value>, id3 = <value> });
```

Among other things (like AJAX calls with jQuery, where you use Json for specifying parameters). It would make things more readable. It would also help if you're using, or going to use, T4MVC.

Comment: great advice, especially the ajax. I am looking up T4 now too.