# mvc conflicting route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes that are satisfying two different urls. how can i remove ambiguity?

Depending on which is first in the list is which is being picked up.

downloadFile and isEdit as both nullable bool.

```
context.MapRoute("Asset_GetImage", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{assetId}/{downloadFile}");
context.MapRoute("News_Read", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{newsId}/{isEdit}");
```

thanks

Comment: Not really an answer, but why not just make the route more generic?`Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{condition}`  Or take out the boolean: `Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}` then pass the boolean in the query string?  eg `http://example.com/news/read/100?isEdit=true`

Comment: I see your suggestion of the querystring. I wanted to show you a post i made the other day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541954/mvc3-routes-setup-as-id-id2-id3

Comment: I don't think it's really necessary to make every possible search parameter part of a URL just because we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make the routes more specific.

For example, specify the `{controller}` for each of these:

```
context.MapRoute("Asset_GetImage", "Admin/Asset/{action}/{assetId}/{downloadFile}");
context.MapRoute("News_Read", "Admin/News/{action}/{newsId}/{isEdit}");
```

you just need to make sure the controller default is added.

as an example from one of my apps:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Calendar",
    "Account/Calendar/{Year}/{Month}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Calendar", Year = DateTime.Now.Year, Month = DateTime.Now.Month }
);
```

`{controller}` and `{action}` aren't in the route but the defaults are still set so it knows what to do with it

Answer (score 4):

You don't need separate routes at all; you are collecting the exact same data types in each.

Just change `assetId` and `newsId` both to simply `id` and code your controllers accordingly. The controller name is already in the URL.

Comment: Barber: Is there no other way? As per this post i made, I wanted to move away from generic variable names. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541954/mvc3-routes-setup-as-id-id2-id3

Comment: `id` is not 'generic'. `newsId` is redundant. But I won't argue the point further; To do what you want to do, you need differing static parts of the URLs; Remove the variable `controller` parameters and instead take static ones, and assign to the controller that way.

Comment: Not sure if I am clear on this. Could you please provide an example? `Remove the variable controller parameters and instead take static ones`